# Old netbeans web app with woodstock

Tags: java, netbeans, woodstock

I am having pretty much this same issue:
[JavaEE/NetBeans Library Referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392726/javaee-netbeans-library-referencing)

I have done what is suggested by downloading Netbeans 6.7 and Glassfish 2, but I still don't have the libraries needed.

Here's what one of my files looks like:

```
import com.sun.data.provider.RowKey;
import com.sun.data.provider.impl.CachedRowSetDataProvider;
import com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractPageBean;
import com.sun.sql.rowset.CachedRowSetXImpl;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Body;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Button;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.DropDown;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Form;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Head;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Html;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Label;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Link;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.MessageGroup;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Page;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.StaticText;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.component.TextField;
import com.sun.webui.jsf.model.SingleSelectOptionsList;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.component.UISelectItems;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
```

I do not have any of the com.sun... packages and can't seem to find them anywhere.

I don't have very much experience with web apps/netbeans so any help would be appreciated. I realize that this is very outdated and should probably be migrated to something else, but for now I'd like to just make a few small edits and would rather not rewrite everything.

Thanks!

Comment: install glassfish in netbeans and addthem as server runtime libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally had opened the project in a newer version of Netbeans that didn't have Wodostock/JSF. For some reason, it wouldn't work when opening with the older version of Netbeans. However, after deleting it and opening it again with the old version first, it worked.